# Java DB connectivity via JPA on multiple entity objects

Tags: jpa, jdbc, spring-jdbc

We have a config table which has rows containing queries and a spring boot/java program needs to read the config table and execute the query in each row present in config table and always return a column consists of number of values (count) to generate an alert for various needs. If we write JPA for db connection , need to write 20 entities class/objects for my DB consists of 20 tables. Instead of writing JPA , am thinking to use JDBC direct execution is one of the way to achieve this need and would like to know from our stackoverflow community is there any other approach do we have?